# Enable/ Create SSO (Single Sign On) in Asp.Net MVC applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, single-sign-on

I want to implement/enable SSO (Single Sign On) on my `Asp.Net MVC` applications.

Please consider the points below below for your kind suggestions:

- I have 3 `Asp.Net MVC` applications where I want to enable SSO for them.
- I know I can achieve SSO by `ADFS` (Active directory Federation Services), **but I don't want to use it** as I want my external users (end-users) to login in all my 3 applications via SSO.
- (Correct me If I wrong here because as far as I know, `ADFS` can be used for Active Directory users (meaning company-wide internal users) and **not** for external end-users. If we can use `ADFS` for external users, please do let me know how we should achieve it.
- I also don't want to use `OpenID`.
- I want to build SSO own for these 3 applications and want to enable SSO between them.
- I want to build SSO that can be used in production environment for
  these 3 applications.

Could you please give me your suggestions on it about how would I achieve SSO by considering all above points?

Thanks in advance and all suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your applications in the same domain?  If so, can you use [Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Comment: Can I deploy/set www.site1.com and www.site2.com at same domain? (I really don't understand in depth network things) , But is it possible? If it's possible to deploy 2 different application on same domain and possible to access by different domain name (like. www.site1.com and www.site2.com), then it will resolve my issue.. Please suggest on it..

Comment: @nunu, To do this you'd need a common domain - e.g. www.site1.mydomain.com and www.site2.mydomain.com.  Then you'd have to set the Domain of your FormsAuthentication cookie to the common domain (mydomain.com) so the cookie can be shared between the sites.

Comment: My last question to you is, Is it possible to make Form authentication in such a way where (Active directory users) can use Window authentication and Form authentication can be used by external users!(end user).. Is it possible to treat one application to use both mechanism of authentication? both form and window authentication.

Comment: @nunu, have a look at the following article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion would be to use the IdentityServer (http://thinktecture.github.com/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/), a replacement for ADFS, which uses the same authentication protocol (WS-Federation) but allows you to plugin your custom membership provider.

In addition, the IdentityServer supports some features ADFS lacks and is quite extensible.

Comment: Can I trust Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 and use for enterprise applications?